# Using LESS with MVC5 in Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2 and installed Web Essentials.

I had thought this was going to make adding LESS to my views a piece of cake, but am missing something.

The editor is great, and I imagine that it is compiling to css on save...

But I don't know where the generated css is, and I don't have any clue as to how to get it reference in my view.

I've tried a lot of searching, but can't get through the web of links about installing this and the features of that.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a .less file and save, the Web Essentials will compile and generate the .css and .min.css files. You will see an arrow in your solution explorer, or you can also confirm in your file system that the files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used less with vs2013 but I have used sass and my guess would be the same. By default the generated css gets generated in the same directory as the source (as it seemed to me) but you can check via tools>options>web essentials and there should be a set of options for less compile on save, build and directory to name but a few.

If you right click on the solution there should be an option to create a web essentials settings file for the solution - these create and adds a json file of web essentials settings to the solution which means your settings are local to the solution which could be important if you are changing the output directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  There are a lot of things I need to look into now.